# Custom NewCommandEvent throwing exceptions

Tags: wxpython

The following is causing one of two exceptions.

Calling `wx.PostEvent(self, MyEvent())` in the `MyPanel.OnButton` method will throw either:

1. `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` If I call the code as pasted, without any arguments.
2. `TypeError: in method 'new_PyCommandEvent', expected argument 2 of type 'int'` if I pass in any non-integer value to the MyEvent() constructor.

An old, broken forum post I found suggested that I need to pass in the object ID of whatever object is supposedly initiating the event. I can do that via:

`wx.PostEvent(self, MyEvent(e.EventObject.GetId()))`

-and that works. But,

1. Every other example I can find online doesn't supply any arguments to the newly instantiated event, so I assume I'm overlooking something.
2. I'm not sure the integer I'm getting from GetId() is correct... seems like ids may be optional?

-

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

# Custom Events

MyEvent, EVT_MYEVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent()

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, label="Button 1")
        sizer.Add(self.button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnButton(self, e):
        e.Skip()
        ##
        # only works if I throw in an Int in the constructor but most 
        # of the tutorials don't do this.
        wx.PostEvent(self, MyEvent()) 


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title=""):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title)
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)  

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title="Event Propagation")
        self.frame.Show()
        self.Bind(EVT_MYEVENT, self.OnMyEvt)
        return True

    def OnMyEvt(self, e):
        print("MY EVENT HAS HAPPENED!")
        e.Skip()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you do not require a `Command Event` and that a normal event would do.
Change:

```
MyEvent, EVT_MYEVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent()
```

to:

```
MyEvent, EVT_MYEVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
```

It should work as you want it to.

If you do require a `command event` you will need to provide an `id`
Quickly mocking up your code (it may need further work):

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

# Custom Events

MyEvent, EVT_MYEVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent()
CMD_ID = wx.NewId()
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, CMD_ID, label="Button 1")
        sizer.Add(self.button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton,id=CMD_ID)

    def OnButton(self, e):
        e.Skip()
        ##
        # only works if I throw in an Int in the constructor but most 
        # of the tutorials don't do this.
        id = e.GetId()
        wx.PostEvent(self, MyEvent(id,myid=id)) 


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title=""):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title)
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)  

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title="Event Propagation")
        self.frame.Show()
        self.Bind(EVT_MYEVENT, self.OnMyEvt)
        return True

    def OnMyEvt(self, e):
        print("MY EVENT HAS HAPPENED!")
        e.Skip()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Potentially. I'm going along with a tutorial and they used a command event. Could be a typo though. I'll give your suggest a shot tomorrow.